# How to rename a bunch of files in Linux?

Tags: bash, shell

I am pretty new to linux, and I ran into a problem while using the mv command. I have a folder of screenshots, each named something along the lines of "Screenshot_20231001_161001.png, and I want to rename them to something easier to move, like 1.png, 2.png, etc.

Any ideas?

```
for f in *.png; do mv -- "$fcounter=1
for f in *.png; do
  mv -- "$f" "test$counter.png"
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
" "${f%.js}.html"; done
```

*I saw a script similar to what i needed on another page (I think they wanted to rename js files to html) and thought to use a version for pngs, but to no luck*

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "rename them to something easier to move". Renaming **is** moving.

Comment: Take a look to mmv(1) command: https://manpages.org/mmv

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` read in 2 input from `cat -n` result (like `enumerate` in python) :

```
find Screenshot_*.png | cat -n | xargs -n 2 sh -c "mv \$1 \$0.png"
```

This means it will rename sequentially like `1.png`, `2.png` ... based on `find` result.

result:

```
# ls
10.png  12.png  14.png  16.png  18.png  1.png   21.png  23.png  25.png  27.png  29.png  3.png  5.png  7.png  9.png
11.png  13.png  15.png  17.png  19.png  20.png  22.png  24.png  26.png  28.png  2.png   4.png  6.png  8.png
```

#### Note

1. Sample output from `find Screenshot_*.png | cat -n`

```
     1  Screenshot_1696319356.png
     2  Screenshot_1696319360.png
     3  Screenshot_1696319372.png
     4  Screenshot_1696319374.png
     5  Screenshot_1696319376.png
     6  Screenshot_1696319378.png
     7  Screenshot_1696319380.png
     8  Screenshot_1696319382.png
     9  Screenshot_1696319384.png
    10  Screenshot_1696319386.png
    11  Screenshot_1696319388.png

    ...
```

2. If you want to adjust sorting condition, you can put `sort` command before the `cat -n`.

Comment: Note 2 is well taken, may even want to include the fact the result of `find` will be unsorted to emphasize the point the user may want to adjust sorting ....

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

count=1
for f in *.png; do
    mv -n -v -- "$f" "$((count++)).png"
done
```

- `$((count++))` expands to the current value of the `count` variable and also increments it.
- The `-n` option to `mv` prevents it from overwriting an existing file.
- The `-v` option to `mv` causes it to print the old and new file names.
- The `--` argument to `mv` indicates that there are no more options.  It ensures that the code will work even if renaming a file whose name begins with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below script for your case:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the starting number for renaming
start=1

# Loop through the files and rename them
for file in *.png; do
  # Get the file extension
  extension="${file##*.}"
  # Create the new filename
  new_filename="$start.$extension"
  
  # Check if the new filename already exists
  if [ -e "$new_filename" ]; then
    echo "File already exists: $new_filename. Skipping."
  else
    # Rename the file
    mv "$file" "$new_filename"
    # Increment the counter
  fi
  start=$((start + 1))
done

echo "Renaming complete."
```

You have to create this script in the **same directory** where your files are present. Also, don't forget to give the required permissions for this script and execute them for your desired results.

Comment: it's worh testing if the destination already exists, otherwise it will get overwritten and lost. also, if the script gets run twice on the same set of files, it would make sense for nothing to get renamed the second time.

Comment: In his case, I think he wants to organize his screenshots on the PC with a proper name. So there won't be any files with the same name.

Comment: adding an assertion that there aren't any files with same name protects against that ceasing to be true when the code is reused somewhere else: cf. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341576

Comment: I totally get you. Thank you for suggesting and pointing it out in my answer. I have edited my script and I have it can be reused.

Comment: the canonical example is probably the code that aborts with the message "this can't happen". an alternative when you don't think tests are worth writing, or if you think they would obscure the focus of the code in an answer, is to state your assumptions as you did in your first comment and let the user of the code decide for themself

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `find` to search for files starting with `Screenshot_` and ending with `.png` and then pipe the output to `awk` to generate the new file names.

check this out

```
find . -iname 'Screenshot_*.png' | awk 'BEGIN{ a=1 }{ printf "mv %s %d.png\n", $0, a++ }' | sh
```

Result

```
1.png  2.png  3.png  4.png  5.png  6.png  7.png  8.png
```